# Is it possible to change the routing preference on an existing Azure public IP address?

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-powershell

When creating a public IP in Azure, you can set the Routing Preference to "Microsoft Network" or "Internet Routing". But looking at an existing public IP in the Azure Portal, that property doesn't appear editable. Is there any way to edit it? Perhaps via CLI/Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Routing Preference for a public IP in Azure is not directly editable after the IP address is created. The Routing Preference is set during the creation of the public IP resource and cannot be modified afterwards